# PhD application: should I mention more than one faculty member in my SOP?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

So I am confused by this for quite a while. Intuitively, mentioning more than one faculty member in SOP can backfire since it put the people you mentioned into a pretty awkward situation. But in another way, it might be a good thing for the board to see an applicant is flexible. Out of idea. Looking for advice.

Thx

Comment: I think the country matters here, and the extent to which your area expects you to come in with a specific advisor vs. decide/finalize once you arrive.

Comment: @Dawn Hi sorry for not being clear. I'm applying for US grad schools and it's usually encouraged to mention the people you are interested to work with.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is always a good thing to mention specific mentors by name - it helps you get recognized and demonstrates you have a grasp on what you want to work on. The fact that there are two faculty you'd be happy with shows you may integrate well, provided the research interests are somewhat similar. The best approach is to contact both of these individuals personally, by email or by phone. This proves your interest and probably guarantees your application will be looked over carefully.  I don't think that listing two potential mentors will set you back, but you could be put into a situation where you have to choose.  If that happens, congrats, you made it into grad school. I've never heard of a PI dismissing a qualified candidate because he/she applied to more than one person.